# Creando un Caching en Java, qué framework utilizar?

Tags: java

Nunca he utilizado un Caché en Java. El problema aquí es al cargar más de 1 millon y más de registros a una "ArrayList" de una base de datos y hacer algo de selección y filtrado de la información. Estoy pensando hacer una memoria Caché para mejorar el rendimiento (tiempo) de mi APP. De antemano he encontrado alternativas para esto por ejemplo EHCache, OSCache y JCS alguna sugerencia de cual usar?

Comment: Tienes que hacerlo si o si con "Caching" ? porque podrías usar una base de datos que esté orientada a este tipo de operaciones, como podría ser MongoDb y asi simplificas el trabajo hace poco estuve haciendo pruebas metiendo un millon de datos y lo hace realmente rápido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **[JBOSS cache](http://jbosscache.jboss.org/)**: Soporta LRU, LFU, MRU, Expiración, Tamaño de elementos y FIFO. No soporta cacheado de las respuestas de la capa de presentación. Su api es simple y potente. Sus métodos ofrecen acceso sincronizado seguro. En cuanto al espacio de memoria, guarda en disco datos cuando el espacio es crítico. Soporta cachés distribuidas. Espera la actualización de la caché a la finalización de las transacciones en caso de que la modificación sea dependiente. De tal forma que si existe un rollback sobre la transacción los cambios en la caché no se ejecutan. Permite compartir elementos dentro de la misma máquina de Java. Es escalable, pero no la más escalable. No soporta el estándar JSR-107.
- **[OSCache](https://github.com/nicklockwood/OSCache)** Soporta LRU y FIFO, y cualquier otro algoritmo personalizado. Soporta el cacheo de la capa de presentación soportando JSTL y JSP. Permite controlar el vaciado de caché. Soporta caché distribuida. Permite intercambiar aobjetos en la misma instancia de la máquina virtual. Permite el uso de caché en disco. Cuando un objeto se borra de la caché sigue ocupando espacio en disco. Es altamente escalable. Sigue el estándar JCache –JSR107 standard. Es más lenta que JBOSS caché
- **[JCS](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/)**: Soporta LRU y MRU. No soporta el guardado del resultado de la capa de presentación. Permite almacenar información en memoria o en disco remoto con RMI. Soporta el intercambio de objetos dentro de la misma máquina virtual de Java. Es altamente escalable. In JCS el area de cache puede estar en memoria, espacio en disco indexado, caché remota ejecutada sobre otras cachés. Soporta JCache. En cuanto a velocidad es mejor que OSCache pero peor que JBOS Caché.
- **[EhCache](http://www.ehcache.org/)**: Soporta LRU, LFU y FIFO. Puede guardar 100G de datos en disco y acceder a ellos de forma rápida. Además comprime los HTTPResponse del buscador y el buscador descomprime la respuesta y la muestra. También permite cachear JSP dinámicos. No soporta JSTL. Permite distribución de cachés de forma flexible. Las últimas actualizaciones también permite RMI. Tiene un api SOAP y REST. Permite compartir elementos dentro de la misma máquina virtual. El api de java es sencillo. Es más rápida que JBOS.

Puedes obtener tus propias conclusiones, pero personalmente yo prefiero EhCache